# Android Studio ¿Como detectar checkBox activado de los ítems de un recycler view?

Tags: android, android-studio, recyclerview, checkbox

**Descripción:**

Tengo una actividad la cual contiene un recycler view, debajo un botón "Aceptar" y debajo un text view el cual mostrará los ítems seleccionados del recycler.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imágen, este recycler view contiene solo un Text View y un solo Check Box, pero muestra 20 items (20 paises distintos). Cuando el usuario active los **checkboxes** correspondientes a cada país que él quiera seleccionar **(por ejemplo: El usuario selecciona 5 checkboxes)** presionará el botón "Aceptar" y el texto de los ítems seleccionados se va a poner en el **Text View** que está debajo del **Button** "Aceptar".

**¿Como puedo detectar que check-boxes se seleccionaron como para poder obtener el texto (pais) correspondiente?**

**Adjunto el código de mi model_recycler**

```
public class model_recycler_paises{
    String pais;

    public model_recycler_paises(String pais){
        this.pais = pais;
    }
}
```

**Adjunto el código XML de mi actividad:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_paises"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_paises"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Aceptar"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recycler_paises"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_paises"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Argentina / Chile / Perú"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bt_paises"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te ofrezco una solución muy práctica.  En tu modelo de datos model_recycler_paises, declara otro atributo: `Boolean isSelected`.

De esta manera, cuando recibes la posición del item en tu adapter para hacer el populate, la recuperas de tu lista y seteas el valor isSelected por el valor del checkbox, que será false la primera vez.  Cuando el usuario haga click, al capturarlo en el listener, la posición se seteará a true, que es el valor del checkbox.

Y para recuperar los valores y hacer el populate del TextView, el adapter debe tener un método del tipo `public List<String> getCountries()` que devolverá una lista de los países.  Para esto, debes filtrar tu lista por el valor `isSelected == true`.

Con este approach, también previenes que al hacer el scroll de la Recycler View, cuando hay que pintar el estado de los checkbox al reciclarse la vista, que se haga de forma correcta.

Comment: Me hiciste dar cuenta que era más sencillo de lo que parecía. Muchas gracias, me sirvió!